# Accessing variables across scripts (or classes) in Unity not working

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game in Unity, and I need help with accessing variables across scripts (or classes). I have a script that runs on the spawned empty object and my `Start()` function looks like this:

```
Moneymanager moneymanager = GetComponent<Moneymanager>();
moneymanager.addMoney();
Invoke("despawn", 10f);
```

I just need there that when the object spawns, it will increase the amount of money of the player. In the canvas script, in `Update()` function, I have this:

```
moneyText.text = "$ " + playerMoney.ToString();
```

When I run it, the money doesn't increase. And I dont' know why:(.

I tried many types of accessing the variable of different class:

```
Moneymanager moneymanager;
Moneymanager moneymanager = new Moneymanager();
Moneymanager moneymanager = GetComponent<Moneymanager>();
```

but I didn't get working any of these.

Comment: There's not enough information to know what you're doing. Consider putting together a [mcve].

Comment: if Moneymanager is a monobehavior youi dont do new MoneyManager, you addcomponent, if its not a monobehavior chances are you cant get it as a component...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just need there that when the object spawns

So the `Moneymanager` component is not attached to your spawning money object!

[`Component.GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html) forwards to [`gameObject.GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) and is looking for your `Moneymanager` component **on the very same GameObject** your just spawned component is attached to!

---

Now - assuming there is only a single instance of `Moneymanager` ever - the easiest (and lazy) fix for this is switching to e.g. [`FindAnyObjectByType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindAnyObjectByType.html)

> Retrieves any active loaded object of Type type.

which is a new faster variant of [`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html)

---

Or you learn and go for proper programming patterns - and **no**, I'm not referring to the *Singleton pattern* at this point; it would probably an option as well - again a lazy and quite controversial one ;)

Rather, something in your scene is spawning those new instances.

This something sits in the scene and can very well "know" (have a reference to) your `Moneymanager` in the same scene.

So

- first of all why do your new spawned objects need to add the money to the manager and not the thing that spawned them?
- or - if the above really is no option (for instance e.g. you only add the money if the player interacts with the spawned items) - you inject either a callback or the `Moneymanager` reference into your spawned objects.

  So e.g.

  ```
   public class YourSpawnedThing : MonoBehaviour
   {
       private Moneymanager _moneymanager;

       public void Initilaize(Moneymanager moneymanager)
       {
           _moneymanager = moneymanager;
       }
   }
  ```

  and then the moment you spawn it

  ```
   [SerializeField] YourSpawnedThing prefab;
   [SerializeField] Moneymanager referenceToMoneyManager;

   ...

   var spawnedThing = Instatiate(prefab);
   spawnedThing.Initilaize(referenceToMoneyManager);
  ```

This is basically a **Dependency Injection Pattern** - just without using one of the many available "magic" dependency injection libraries.

---

Side note: Canvas is quite expensive. If you change a text every frame then every frame it will also have to re-layout and render the entire Canvas again!

Instead of using `Update` you should rather only modify the text when the value if actually changed.

You could use a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) for this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Backing field for <see cref="playerMoney"/>
/// </summary>
private int _playerMoney;

public int playerMoney
{
    get => _playerMoney;
    set
    {
        _playerMoney = value;
        moneyText.text = "$ " + playerMoney.ToString();
    }
}
```

This way whenever you assign a value to `playerMoney` it will automatically keep the `moneyText` in sync.